# NoSuchMethodError at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a really simple code in Java which reads data from `hdfs`

```
try{
    InputStream s = new GzipCompressorInputStream(hdfsFileSystem.open(filePath), false);
    ByteStreams.copy(s, outputStream);
    s.close();
}
catch (Exception ex){
    logger.error("Problem with file "+ filePath,ex);
}
```

**Sometimes** (not always) it throws me exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.getBlockReader(DFSInputStream.java:1099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:749)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:793)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.read(DataInputStream.java:149)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.init(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:136)
        at org.apache.commons.compress.compressors.gzip.GzipCompressorInputStream.<init>(GzipCompressorInputStream.java:129)
        [...]
```

On line below line:

```
InputStream s = new GzipCompressorInputStream(hdfsFileSystem.open(filePath), false);
```

I am using bellow maven dependency to load hadoop client:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this problem? Of cource I can change `catch(Exception e)` to `catch(Error e)`, but it isn't a solution just workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like in yours classpath present several "commons-io.jar" with different versions. 
Method "closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)" appeared in version 2.0.
Sometimes "commons-io.jar" with older version loaded first, and exception appeared.
Classpath fix required.